# caching for bigquery queries

Tags: caching, google-bigquery

I am running queries on BigQUERY ON DATASETS that are around few hundreds of milions or records.

This is faster then other solutions, however, queries do take 10-30 sec, which is not suitable for online queries.

Is there any best practice or cache/in-mem technology that one use to make it run faster?

I am also considering the option of creating summarized/aggregation tables, but then I could do it in other databases.

Comment: I'm currently evaluating bigquery for my use cases, did you get anywhere with caching data? I have same exact problem - my queries come back between 3 - 30 secs, I was hoping to pull this data directly from bigquery from app engine app, but time taken to run these queries suggest bigquery isn't good enough for me to use it directly.

Answer (score 2):

If querying is too slow, and caching works, you could save the output of your queries by specifying a destination table. You can then read the results from the destination table via the tabledata.list api rather than running the query again. Otherwise, I don't know of any best practices that make queries faster, other than optimizing the queries themselves.

Comment: I haven't tried this work around, but it sounds like creating aggregation tables. I know it's been a while since you answered this question, has any patterns to cache data with bigquery emerged since?